# ¿Qué pasa cuando se acaba las consultas gratuitas en Google Maps Api?

Tags: google-maps, google-distancematrix-api, google-api

Entre la documentación de una de las APIs de Google Maps ([link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/usage-limits?hl=ES)), vienen los términos de uso, pero en ninguna parte de la documentación aparece que pasa cuando excedes los términos de uso y no agregas una tarjeta de crédito (este sería mi caso, ya que deseo que cuando se exceda mostrarle al usuario un mensaje de error).

Lo más probable que creo que pase es que se devuelva una respuesta en el formato escogido (JSON o XML), pero deseo saber cuál es el formato de dicho mensaje.

Si alguien conoce el link de donde pueda encontrar esta documentación o conozca el formato que se devuelve. [Aquí](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro?hl=es-419#Restrictions) dejo el link de la documentación sobre dicha API.

Comment: Hola, en la documentacion que pusiste https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro?hl=es-419#Restrictions en la seccion de codigos de estado se indica que el valor de "status" se pondrá en "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" si excedes los usos de la api, en este caso en el que terminaste los usos gratuitos de la misma

Comment: los limites del uso gratuito los puedes ver aqui https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage?hl=Es

Comment: En ese caso tendrías que verificar el `status` antes de lanzar la petición.   Más o menos así: `if (status  == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {  //aquí se puede  }else {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) { //Aquí se excedió el límite, esperar o actuar en consecuencia }}` Quizá [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11825245/5587982) te sea de ayuda en ese sentido.